# Schoen curvature estimates (part 2)

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm referring to the article ''Estimates for stable minimal surfaces in three dimensional manifolds'' by Richard Schoen.
I have a question about the proof of theorem 1. In the last step of the proof (after (14)) I don't understand how the author uses (10) and (14) to obtain the estimate that concludes the theorem. In detail I have some problem to conclude when $ \left[R^{-2}(1+S_{P_0,R}R^2)\right]\geq 1 $ . Note that $ \lim_{R\rightarrow 0}\left[R^{-2}(1+S_{P_0,R}R^2)\right]=+\infty $ so the stated case is not empty.It is true that the case explicitly treated in the article is $ R \geq 2 $ but this restriction should not influence the estimate apart for rescaling the balls used in the proof.

Thank you